# FLV video upload?

Tags: php

I use `if($_FILE['type']['video/flv'])` but it does not upload it. Can anyone help me? I'll be thankful to you.

Comment: You are using incorrect syntax: You need to *compare*, i.e. `$_FILE['type'] == 'video/flv'` also, the MIME type transmitted by the browser is highly unreliable. It's not wise to rely on it

Answer (score 2):

Don't rely on `$_FILES['somefilefield']['type']`. There are many reasons why a browser might fill it in with the 'wrong' media type. At best you can use the submitted type as an advisory for guessing what kind of file you've got, but you should never require it to match anything in particular.

In this case, most Windows desktops won't be set up to have any filetype association for the `video/x-flv` MIME type. So to Windows, a `.flv` file is nothing but an unknown binary file, and that's what it'll tell your server it's sending.

Comment: +1. To identify an uploaded file, better use server side techniques. The [`getid3`](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) library claims to be able to fetch info from FLVs.

Answer (score 0):

The mime type for flv is now `'video/x-flv'`, have a try.